# UITableViewCell customizing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to figure out, pros and cons in below two. Both works fine.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:      (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = nil;
    MyChildUITableViewCell *childTableViewCell =
    (MyChildUITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyChildUITableViewCell"];

    tableViewCell = childTableViewCell;
    return tableViewCell;
}
```

OR

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    MyChildUITableViewCell *childTableViewCell = nil;

    childTableViewCell = (MyChildUITableViewCell*)
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyChildUITableViewCell"];
    return childTableViewCell;
}
```

Comment: whats the question title have to do with the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is right now, those two code options are the same. There is no particular pro or con with either, if that is all that you will do with the code.

The only pro I can even think of is for option 1 if you plan on having different types of cells in the table. That code will setup nicely to handle different types of cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:      (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = nil;

    if (conditionsForCellOfType1) {
        MyChildUITableViewCell *childTableViewCell =
        (MyChildUITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyChildUITableViewCell"];

        tableViewCell = childTableViewCell;
    } else {
        DifferentTypeOfCell *differentCell =
        (DifferentTypeOfCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DifferentTypeOfCell"];

        tableViewCell = differentCell;
    }

    return tableViewCell;
}
```